# Можно ли кастомизировать расположение файлов после Publish?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Сейчас если выполнять Publish, то все сборки кидаются в одну папку.

А можно ли как-нибудь их сгруппировать по папкам?

Например, хотелось бы, что бы в корне лежал EXE-файл.

Comment: `Publish` же доступен только для `Web` проектов, о каком `EXE` идет речь?

Comment: Ну так можно опубликовать Net Core и создастся exe-файл.